# Ansible temp dir change

Tags: ansible

Ansible version 2.9.2

Is it possible to change ansible temp dir for one playbook only?
I have VMs with r/o root. So, the playbook fails.
Even if I run my playbook under root user on target VM it can't create ansible temp files that it creates in current user's home dir on target VM.
I know that I can change it in ansible.cfg file, but I need it only for one VM type.

I need to make changes to other not r/o drives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q: ***"Is it possible to change ansible temp dir for one playbook only? I have VMs with r/o root."***

A: Yes. It's possible. Configure the variable [ansible_remote_tmp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/sh.html).

In some cases, a better solution to this problem is [ANSIBLE_PIPELINING](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-pipelining). Quoting from [Risks and limitations of become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#risks-and-limitations-of-become):

> Use pipelining. When pipelining is enabled, Ansible does not save the module to a temporary file on the client. Instead, it pipes the module to the remote python interpreter’s stdin. Pipelining does not work for python modules involving file transfer (for example: copy, fetch, template), or for non-python modules.

---

Notes:

- Quoting from [Release notes](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.5/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.5.rst#minor-changes-4):

> The ANSIBLE_REMOTE_TMP environment variable has been added to supplement (and override) ANSIBLE_REMOTE_TEMP. This matches the spelling of the config value. ANSIBLE_REMOTE_TEMP will be deprecated in the future.

- `remote_tmp` is not among configuration options in [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings)
- See [`remote_tmp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/sh.html#parameter-remote_tmp) parameter of the [sh](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/sh.html#sh-posix-shell-bin-sh) plugin.
- See open [bugs](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ANSIBLE_REMOTE_TMP+is%3Aopen)

Answer (score 2):

I understood with the help of the documentation above how to replace environment variables.

For example:

```
- hosts: hostnames
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp
  tasks:
  ...
```

Also, it's possible to replace in the separate tasks.

[Ansible documentation about playbook environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html)